# Rspec check if a block is yield with correct arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I want to check if status_params are passed and if correct:

```
  def send_push_notification(order, parse_events)
    Parse.publish_status(order.deliverer_id) do
      status_params(
        parse_events[:role],
        order,
        generate_message(message)
      )
    end
  end

  def status_params(role, order, message)
    {
      role: role,
      status: order.status,
      order_id: order.id,
      alert: message
    }
  end
```

My rspec is so far:

```
      it 'sends push notification to the deliverer when the order is ready' do
        expect(Parse).
          to receive(:publish_status).with(order.deliverer_id).once
        subject.update_order(
          order,
          status: 'ready'
        )
      end
```

so it only checks if deliverer_id passes. What about the block? I need to make sure these are the correct arguments. Please help!

Comment: If the block just calls a method that returns a hash, why use a block at all? Why not pass the hash as a an arg to `Parse.publish_status`?

Comment: The fact that you're trying to test the arguments that are passed as a block make me think there's some design problem there.

Comment: @lcguidawhat do you mean? could specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [block implementation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation) to call the passed block yourself in order to inspect its result:

```
expect(Parse).to receive(:publish_status).with(order.deliverer_id).once do |&block|
  result = block.call
  expect(result).to be_a(Hash)
  expect(result[:status]).to eq('ready')
  # ...
end
```